# How to define top-3 rating?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have 3 tables:

```
users 
id  device
11  SM-G955F
12  iPhone8,2
13  SM-G955F
14  LG-H812
15  SM-G955F
16  SM-G955F
17  iPhone8,2
```

2.

```
activity
user_id login_time
11  2018-05-11
12  2018-05-11
13  2018-05-11
14  2018-05-12
14  2018-05-14
15  2018-05-14
11  2018-05-14
12  2018-05-14
```

3

```
payments

user_id
15
17
11
```

What query should I do to make top-3 rating of devices on 14.05.2018 according to number of user from activity ?

Need three column:

```
device      number_of_users         number_of_users 
            (from activity)         (from payments if there were)
```

This is my query:

```
select u.device, count(distinct u.id) as number_of_users from users u inner 
join activity a on a.user_id = u.id where a.login_time = '2018-04-18' group 
by u.device order by number_of_users DESC limit 3;
```

But I can't display users from payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want another `join` and `count(distinct)`:

```
select u.device, count(distinct u.id) as number_of_users,
       count(distinct p.user_id) as number_of_payment_users
from users u inner join
     activity a
     on a.user_id = u.id left join
     payments p
     on p.user_id = u.id
where a.login_time = '2018-04-18'
group by u.device
order by number_of_users desc
limit 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

use left join for  payment

```
    select u.device, count(distinct u.id) as number_of_users,
  count(p.user_id) as cntpay
     from users u inner 
     join activity a on a.user_id = u.id 
     left join  paymets p on u.id=p.user_id
     where a.login_time = '2018-05-14'
    group by u.device
    order by number_of_users DESC limit 3
```

Comment: thanks, but I've got ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.id' in 'field list'

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков what is the column name of your activity table

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list'